# Flex and embbed fonts shared library

Tags: apache-flex, performance, fonts, shared-libraries

I have a question regarding flex and embed fonts , i want to have a library of embed fonts that will have about 30 different fonts .

Is there any way i can only load the fonts that i use? ( dynamicaly )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page (from the Flex docs) has one approach:
[Loading style sheets at run time](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html).

> By loading style sheets at run time,
>   you can load images (for graphical
>   skins), fonts, type and class
>   selectors, and programmatic skins into
>   your Flex application without
>   embedding them at compile time.

You might also find something useful here: [AS3 Runtime Font Loading](http://nochump.com/blog/?p=20).